# RelayCommands get executed multiple times

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7.1, mvvm-light, async-await, relaycommand

I am using MVVM Light in a Windows Phone 7 (7.1 using the wp8 SDK and VS Ultimate 2012) application that asynchroneously retrieves data from a web service application. I use RelayCommands on each page that execute async methods to get the data then navigate to the next page. For example, in one of my ViewModels, I declare the following ICommand :

```
public ICommand ShowTreatmentDetailsCommand { get; set; }
```

then, in the VM's constructor, I assign it this way :

```
ShowTreatmentDetailsCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowTreatmentDetails);
```

and here's the method called by that command :

```
private async void ShowTreatmentDetails()
{
    try
    {
        Treatment refreshedTreatment = await treatmentService.LoadSingle(SelectedTreatment.id, LoggedUser.logon, LoggedUser.pwHash);

        if (refreshedTreatment != null)
        {
            DrugGroup anaestGroup = null;
            DrugGroup surgGroup = null;

            IEnumerable<DrugGroup> groups = await drugGroupService.Load(
                refreshedTreatment.id,
                LoggedUser.logon,
                LoggedUser.pwHash);

            anaestGroup = groups
                .Where(g => g.type == DrugType.Anaesthetic)
                .SingleOrDefault<DrugGroup>();

            surgGroup = groups
                .Where(g => g.type == DrugType.Surgical)
                .SingleOrDefault<DrugGroup>();

            Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            parameters.Add(Keys.AnaestDrugGroup, anaestGroup);
            parameters.Add(Keys.SurgDrugGroup, surgGroup);
            parameters.Add(Keys.SelectedTreatment, refreshedTreatment);

            Messenger.Default.Send(parameters);
        }
        else
        {
            // Display error message
        }

        RefreshData();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException) { }
}
```

This command is called from the View's xaml code when an item is selected from a ListBox, using an EventTrigger and the EventToCommand class (but the problem stays the same with button-related commands. Just in case, here's my ListBox element :

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbxTreatmentList"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Treatments}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTreatment, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <int:Interaction.Triggers>
        <int:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <com:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ShowTreatmentDetailsCommand}"
                                PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </int:EventTrigger>
    </int:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <custom:TreatmentListItem PatientName="{Binding patient}"
                                      OpeDescription="{Binding description}"
                                      StartedAt="{Binding startedAt}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And another exaple with a button :

```
<Button Grid.Row="2"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Foreground="{StaticResource BeldicoBlue}"
    BorderBrush="{StaticResource BeldicoBlue}"
    Margin="0,12,0,0"
    Padding="24,12"
    Command="{Binding ValidateCommand}">
    <TextBlock Text="Validate this treatment" FontWeight="ExtraBold" />
</Button>
```

The problem is that, each time the command is fired, the related method gets executed an increasing number of times. I.e. : once at the first call, then twice, then three, four, five... times. Which quickly becomes bandwidth and time consuming, as there is an async service call in the method.

I definitely don't get the reason behind this behavior, can anyone help ?

Comment: Why do you define `public ICommand ShowTreatmentDetailsCommand` and then `ShowTreatmentDetailsCommand = new RelayCommand`. Replace ICommand with RelayCommand. Probably won't fix your problem, but I don't if I get this right. You click on the button, method will be called ONCE. You click on the button again, the method will be called TWICE, is that correct?

Comment: Have you looked at the stack trace of each execution to find out what's triggering the execution?

Comment: @Rudi : I declared my commands as ICommands because ICommand is built in the .NET framework, as opposed to RelayCommands, which inherit the ICommand interface but come with the MVVM Light package. Declaring commands as RelayCommands instead of ICommands makes no difference but I just used ICommand by habit.

And yes, you got the problem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of possible things going on here:

1. You're creating multiple viewmodel instances attached to the page and each one is executing the command.

   Or, more likely:
2. You're not fully accounting for how the `SelectionChanged` event works. This event can be triggered multiple times when the selection changes. If there is a selected item already, the changed event will fire when that item is removed and then again when the new selected item is added.
   If you were using the event handler directly you could query the `SelectionChangedEventArgs` directly to determine what has triggered the event. Your code is ignoring these args though, even though your xaml says you're passing them.

If you change your Action so that it supports these args you could add the check there.
e.g.

```
ShowTreatmentDetailsCommand =
     new RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(ShowTreatmentDetails);
```

and

```
private async void ShowTreatmentDetails(SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.AddedItems.Count >= 1)
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: I also thought about Nr 1, since this also happened to me, but according to his code, I (we) can't see where or when he calls/creates the ViewModel. Good thinking about the SelectionChangedEvent, but he said it also happens when he clicks on a button, so I think it's more likely number 1.

Comment: That actually was solution n°2 for me. I didn't know the SelectionChanged event got fired multiple times at each selection, thanks for sharing the tip. By the way, in my situation, checking args.AddedItems.Count for strict equality to 1 rather than "smaller or equal" works better.

I used to have a similar bug with some buttons but it seems to have been fixed when I refactored my View layer, making it systematically call the CleanViewModel method at each navigation.

Comment: IMHO `SelectionChangedEventArgs` in `Viewmodel` will make the method coupled to view , Hence its cannot testable without mocking the `SelectionChangedEventsArgs` Is there any more elegant way ?